# set default http header request to empty in tcl http

Tags: http, tcl

I would like to set the default http hrader in Tcl http package to empty and then selecetively put some header on my own using a dictionary. I need to do this becasue I see many items (like sock, binary, -binary, -strict, queryoffset etc) in my Tcl http request header which are not present in the header specified by other web browser like firefox. I get correct response in broswer so I want exactly those heater which are send by the brower. For this I need to set the default http header in Tcl http package to empty, and mannually set the headers (which I can do). How do I empty the default headers?

Comment: You _can't_ empty the headers entirely. Tcl always sends some of them. Unless you just open a socket yourself and do everything by hand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not quite sure which header you've got a problem with, but the majority of headers can be set quite easily via the `-headers` option to `http::geturl`:

```
# Easiest to build the option as a dictionary
dict set opts X-Example-Header "fruitbats are mammals and this is nonsense"
dict set opts DNT "1 (Do Not Track Enabled)"

http::geturl $theurl -headers $opts
```

Almost everything can be set or overridden this way, and the things that can't are typically related to the management of the network connection itself (such as keep-alive management, chunking, compression) and are probably best left to the library in the first place, as HTTP/1.1 is a pretty complex protocol for something supposedly stateless.

Note that options to `http::geturl` do not *directly* translate into request options. It's a higher-level interface…